# Static const variable is not constant in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and have two classes Parent and Child.  Parent declares some static const variables in the header, which are then defined in the cpp file.  When I try to use the defines as cases in a switch statement in a child class I get the error: *C2051: case expression not constant*.  So I've done some testing and  the behavior I'm seeing is somewhat inconsistent.

```
// Parent.h
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent(void) { }

  static const unsigned long A = 1;
  static const unsigned long B;
};


// Parent.cpp
#include "Parent.h"

const unsigned long Parent::B = 2;

Parent::Parent()
{
  // Everything works fine here
  unsigned long l;
  switch(l)
  {
  case A:
    break;
  case B:
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}

// Child.h
#pragma once
#include "Parent.h"

class Child :
  public Parent
{
public:
  Child(void);
  virtual ~Child(void) { }

  static const int C = 3;
  static const int D;
};

// Child.cpp
#include "Child.h"

const int Child::D = 4;

Child::Child(void)
{
  unsigned long l;
  switch(l)
  {
  case A:
    break;
  case B:  // C2051: case expression not constant
    break;
  case C:
    break;
  case D:
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

I've also tried specifying `Parent::B` directly, which doesn't solve the issue.  Is there some reason why the expression is constant in all cases except when the variable is inherited from a parent class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use a `static const` integer-type member variable in a constant expression if

- it is initialized with a constant expression and
- that constant expression is visible at the time that it is used.

In your `switch`, the value of `Parent::A` is visible because its initializer is in the Parent.h header file.  The same goes for `Child::C`.  The value of `Child::D` is visible because its initializer occurs earlier in Child.cpp.

However, the value of `Parent::B` is not visible:  C++ source files are compiled separately, so when compiling Child.cpp, the compiler knows that `Parent::B` is a `static const` integer-type member variable, but it doesn't know what its value is.  Thus, it can't be used in a constant expression in Child.cpp.

---

Note that if you ever use `Parent::A` as an object (e.g., `&Parent::A`), you will still need to define `B` in Parent.cpp, using `const unsigned long Parent::A;`, without an initializer, since you put the initializer in the class definition.

Comment: Please, what is the rationale for this? Seems weird since the constant value can be known at compilation time.

Comment: @Antonio:  I've updated my answer to try to explain:  basically, it's because C++ source files are compiled independently.

Comment: @Antonio - If you compile child.cpp before writing parent.cpp, it is not known.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that I think about it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rob:  Sorry:  I was overhauling the answer while you made that typo correction.  Thanks for the correction, though!

Comment: More precisely, only if the initializer is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that Visual Studio let you get away with declaring the const outside of a class declaration. The line

```
static const unsigned long B;
```

inside your Parent class should not be allowed. When I tried your example on the Mac, which uses GNU g++ compiler, I got the following error:

```
error: declaration of 'const long unsigned int Parent::B' outside of class is not definition
```

As for why it works on one class, but not the other; my guess: inside the child.cpp file, the compiler saw that D was indeed declared as a const, but it has no knowledge of how B was defined (or redefined). To make this work, you should move all constant declarations to the class in the .h file and not .cpp file.

Comment: That error message says that it’s about a declaration outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that for the compiler the `static const` is not constant, beacuse at compile time it does not yet have a value, which is needed to compile the `case` statement.

The value is added later at link-time, when `parent.o` is linked to `child.o` (Remember that with plugins or shared libs link time could be as late as runtime).